# How do you install Debian with Windowmaker?

Tags: debian

I would like to install Debian with a desktop other than Gnome. In this case I can't use tasksel but have to install every package with apt-get.

What do I need in order to run Debian with Windowmaker?

Comment: `apt-get install wmaker`

Answer (score 2):

To install Window Maker, type

```
aptitude install wmaker
```

However it is not a desktop environment. It is only a window manager. It means if you want to have a program for every possible task, you will need to install them separately. Of course you can use KDE, Gnome, XFCE and other desktop application with Window Maker.